# How to set click event for a cell of a table column in a Tableview?

Tags: mouseevent, javafx-8, fxml

I have a TableView in one of the Tabs of a TabPane. I want to add a click event on the cell, user id , so that when ever the user clicks on a particular user id , i open a new tab with user specific details. how to  add event listeners to all the cells in a column ?

```
<TableView fx:controller="tableViewController"
    fx:id="tableViewTable" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8">
    <columnResizePolicy>
        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
    </columnResizePolicy>
    <columns>
        <TableColumn text="First Name">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="firstName" />
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn text="Last Name">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="lastName" />
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn text="User Id">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="userId" />
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
    </columns>
</TableView>
```

This blog http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2013/05/detect-mouse-click-on-javafx-tableview.html  talks about capturing the click event  programmatically,  how do I do something similar when using FXML ?

Comment: You can't really do this in FXML; you can only get at the table cells in the cell factory. So you have to do this in the controller. (FXML is pretty much just for layout.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this in the controller. Add a `fx:id` to the table column (say `fx:id="userIdColumn"`), and then in the controller set a cell factory on the column:

```
public class TableViewController {

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<User, String> userIdColumn ;

    public void initialize() {
        userIdColumn.setCellFactory(tc -> {
            TableCell<User, String> cell = new TableCell<User, String>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty) ;
                    setText(empty ? null : item);
                }
            };
            cell.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
                if (! cell.isEmpty()) {
                    String userId = cell.getItem();
                    // do something with id...
                }
            };
            return cell ;
        });

        // other initialization code...
    }

    // other controller code...

}
```

Here I am assuming that your table displays objects of some class `User` that you have created, and that the user id is a `String`. Obviously you can adjust the types as needed.

Comment: I don't completely understand lambda expressions yet , could you please elobarate whats happeing  in the setCellFactory() ?

Comment: The cell factory is a function that maps a table column (which I called `tc` and never used) to `TableCell`s which are used to display the data in each cell in that column. So when the table view needs a table cell for that column, it calls the function you provide.

Comment: I had difficulty comprehending the lambda expression , so did it with the old way of declaring anonymus object. Now I'm able to capture the click event . But now the problem is, the User id  column doesn't show the values any more ? Should I bind the UserId proprty value to the cell in the initialize method ? Earlier the following line code was binding the value . <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="userId" />
            </cellValueFactory>

Comment: You still need the `cellValueFactory`, you just need the `cellFactory` in addition.

Comment: hmm..  when I add the cellFactory  definition it doesn't display the values of userId anymore . I populate the list of users in initialize method

Comment: Update your question with the code. You still have the `cellValueFactory`, and you have the `setText(...)`  call in the `updateItem(...)` method?

Comment: That was it ..  setText () call was missing.  Thanks James